# htaccess dash in rewrite causing issues

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I cant seem to get my htaccess code right for redirecting pages that appear like the below to go to a 410 page, eg:

```
www.domain.com/-c-23.html
www.domain.com/-c-12.html
www.domain.com/-c-755.html
```

Basically, I want a rule whereby anything where "-c-" comes directly after the slash of the domain gets sent to a 410. I have been trying to do this but my code isn't working, so far I have something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/\-c-[0-9]+\.html$ - [G]
```

But this makes no difference at all, any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the leading slash in your regular expression. URI's sent through rules in htacccess files have the leading slash stripped off:

```
RewriteRule ^\-c-[0-9]+\.html$ - [G,L]
```

You also need the `L` flag to immediately stop rewriting. You could also be even more general:

```
RewriteRule ^-c- - [G,L]
```

Comment: Neither of those are working, they work fine when I remove the dash in front of the c so if the link was ".com/c-" then it would work. But as soon as I add in the dash to the rewrite rule it doesnt work for ".com/-c-"